# Can the adjective "ripe" be used with fields? As an attributive or a predicative adjective?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Is it correct to say in a poem or a rap song, "the fields are ripe the wheat is white" Thanks very much.

Comment: Being that this is for a creative work, I'd say you could do almost [anything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._E._Cummings#Poetry).

Comment: "The fields are already ripe for harvest." - John 4:35

Comment: If anything, "the wheat is white" is the weird part for me. I had always felt that wheat had been a hue of [brown or yellow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_(color)).

Comment: Look up "white wheat".

Comment: A rap song about wheat would be interesting, especially white wheat.

Comment: @TRomano as metaphors go it's not the worst.  But if OP is *rapping* about skin color "white bread" is probably better.

Comment: Fields are ripe for harvest won't fit the meter. Whoever downvoted me should be ashamed of themselves. The wheat is white collocated with the fields are ripe is very weird. Ripe FOR harvest is not just ripe. Rap works with meter.

Comment: white wheat for skin color??

Answer (score -3):

The fields are **sown**, and the wheat is **grown**

Fields cannot be ripe though one can say X is ripe for Y.

Ripe and white are slant rhymes: they have the same internal vowel sound.

Sown and grown are ends rhymes, which might be better in rap.

The fields are ripe to my ear just sounds ignorant, sorry. The wheat is ripe does not sound ignorant.

Comment: Really? A downvote for lines that rhyme? Please.

Comment: Not my downvote, but: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fields%20are%20ripe%20for%20harvest%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @TRomano I carry my culture in my head. Google is not culture. It's a hit machine. Hits are not arguments about language.

Comment: Such broad statements are too extreme: you must read through the Google results and assess the attestations, keeping the good, tossing the bad. "The fields are ripe" is well attested both in literal contexts (e.g. agricultural reports to the government) and figurative ones (religious/missionary texts). .

Comment: @TRomano It is not a broad statement. If you take a college writing course, do you think the students would present arguments about writing to the professor based on what is googled? I think the rap line: the fields are ripe and the wheat is white is frankly pretty bad. That cannot be googled.

Comment: "based on what is Googled" is a broad statement, Lambie. Plenty of what Google brings up are valid attestations.  BTW, you added an "and" to the lyric which it does not have, which robs it of much of its poetry.

Comment: I did not add an and. ///the fields are ripe///AND ///the wheat is white///. Last time I checked (an idiomatic expression), poetry (rap is a kind of poetry) is guided by what poets think, not google. And please, we don't use attestation like that in English. Attestation is a highly technical word (mostly legal) in English. Google returns ***hits***.

Comment: The OP's question reads "the fields are ripe the wheat is white". Are you referring to something else? OP also said "a poem or a rap song." Lambie, Google returns hits, some of which are valid attestations. I know what attestations are. They are not "mostly legal".

Comment: What I was objected to were the two phrases and I happened to put in an and. Google does not attest to anything. Only a real, live (undead, non- zombie) person can attest to something, verbally or in writing. An algorithm in a program is not intelligent. It cannot attest to anything at all.

Comment: Lambie, an *attestation*, in this context, is a textual witness to a particular usage. It is a term from lexicography. https://books.google.com/books?id=gEFDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT191&lpg=PT191&dq=lexicography+attestation&source=bl&ots=QX0yE0HHKO&sig=fOpf_z1-JlgBD0cUcpA3oAZD8dg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8vs3Xoq7RAhWLg1QKHRUwDgYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=lexicography%20attestation&f=false  It is not the Google algorithm but (some of) the texts included in its hits which are attestations.

Comment: Actually, one can, of course, attest to usage of a word. But that is not what poetry is about. Rap is poetry and only a person can have an opinion of it. As the phrase only exists here, my opinion is that it ain't great.